# Split doesn't work in align with multiple tab stops

Tags: align, amsmath, mathtools, split

I have equations in an `align` environment with multiple tab stops, and I'd like to use `split` to render just one equation number for multiple lines of equations. However, if I have more than one tab stop per line, I get the error

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<template> }$\hfill \endtemplate
```

Here's an example that works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
f(x) &= y & g(x) &= z \\
h(x) &= a & h(x) &= b
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x) &= y \\
h(x) &= a 
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

and produces the following output.

[image]

Here's an example that doesn't work. Note the only difference from the above two examples is the fact that `split` is being used with multiple tab stops.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f(x) &= y & g(x) &= z \\
h(x) &= a & h(x) &= b
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `equation` and `aligned`?  That gives just a single equation number and can handle multiple tab stops.  (Explained in the documentation for `amsmath`, `texdoc amsldoc`.)

Comment: From amsldoc.pdf "split supports only one alignment (&) column; if more are needed, aligned or alignedat should be used."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you employ an `alignat` environment if you need all equations numbered individually, and an `equation`/`alignedat` nested environment if you need just a single, vertically centered, equation number for all equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
f(x) &= y &\hspace{2.5cm} g(x) &= z \\
h(x) &= a &               h(x) &= b
\end{alignat}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
f(x) &= y &\hspace{2.5cm} g(x) &= z \\
h(x) &= a &               h(x) &= b
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```